# How Relative Pronouns Work

Tags: syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses

A relative pronoun is called "both a conjunction and a pronoun". There are other definitions, but the horribly superficial ones like "connects two sentences" are enough.

Why doesn't anyone say clearly what it is? Are my thoughts below wrong?

- **Car I bought.** (Car: qualified)
- **Who I saw**. (who: qualified - not a conjunction or preposition)

*I think the relative pronoun is a qualifying noun and this is perhaps a very big mistake. That is my basic claim, I am not a linguist. I am just curious about your thoughts.*

---

- ***[Who loves me]*** (Who: qualified)
- ***Girl + [Who loves me]*** (girl: qualified indirectly)

The relative pronoun is semantically related to "girl" but grammatically far, far away from it. The only solution is to put them back to back! And so it is done.

in this case, the relative clause is not in a real (grammatical) relation with the noun it qualifies. Everything works according to syntactic proximity.

Therefore, it is possible to construct sentences like the one below:

- **I know** ***[where you live]*** adjective clause.

The "*where*" here does not have an antecedent because it basically has no grammatical connection with the antecedent! It was all about semantic proximity. Because where, on its own, is a qualifying noun, it has no grammatical connection with the antecedent.

The relative pronoun is not really a conjunction or a marker.

***Noun/Noun Phrase + [RP + adjective clause]*** = Noun Phrase Qualified by Action.

This could of course be wrong. What do you think?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150608/discussion-on-question-by-kadir-how-relative-pronouns-work); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in chat, the "where you live" in "I know where you live" is an interrogative clause, not a relative clause, but I'll try to answer the first part of your question. Consider this sentence:

> She is a girl who loves me.

The structure of this sentence is:

> She is a [girl [who loves me]].

Here, "who loves me" is a relative clause, a kind of finite subordinate clause; this clause acts as a modifier of *girl.* More specifically, it is a *wh*-relative (as opposed to, say, one starting with "that"). The subject in that clause--the subject of the verb *love*--is the relative pronoun *who.* The antecedent of this pronoun is *girl,* which is why we understand that the girl is the person who loves me. Importantly, there is no way that *who* behaves like a conjunction; it's just the subject of the verb within the subordinate clause, which as a whole modifies *girl.*

Now consider this sentence:

> She is a girl who I love.

In more formal contexts, we might use *whom* instead of *who.* The structure of this sentence is:

> She is a [girl [ who [ I love ___ ] ] ].

When the relative pronoun is not the subject (or part of the subject) in the relative clause, we have to move it to the start of the clause, leaving a gap inside of it. The antecedent of this gap is the relative pronoun *who,* and the antecedent of *who* is again *girl.*

Now consider this example:

> She is a girl for whom I feel great affection.

Of course, in less formal contexts, we might use "who I feel great affection for". But the structure of this sentence as given is:

> She is a [girl [ [for whom] [I feel great affection ___] ] ].

Here, what's been moved to the front of the relative clause is not just the relative pronoun but a larger *relative phrase* containing it. (The same is true of the previous example, but there the relative phrase is just the relative pronoun "who" on its own.) Again, there's a gap, whose antecedent in this case is the relative phrase *for whom.* *For whom* is, of course, a prepositional phrase containing the pronoun *whom,* whose antecedent is again *girl.*

The case of bare relatives, like "She is a girl I love," and *that-*relatives, like "She is a girl that I love," is quite different, but that seems to be outside the scope of your question and this answer is long enough.

(As usual, in the above I'm following the analysis given by [Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language).)

Comment: Perfecttt, ı am hapy, thank you.

Comment: You explained it well, I enjoyed learning. I don't want to bore you. Why was the object moved to the beginning? 

Girl I love whom. (Why not like this?) I hope I'm not overwhelming...

Comment: @Kadir It's just a rule of English grammar; I'm not sure what the history of it is.

Comment: This may be because of the syntax (svo) You are very patient and like a real teacher. Thank you for helping me.